# Postgres: Table is shown using \d but shows syntax error while dropping the table

Tags: database, postgresql, relational-database

I have weird issue when I do

```
`temp=# \d
                      List of relations
Schema |             Name              |   Type   |      Owner      
--------+-------------------------------+----------+-----------------
public | ORDER                         | table    | admin
public | ORDER_id_seq                  | sequence | admin `
```

As the table list as shown above. The table name `ORDER` is coming but when I try to drop it, I get the syntax error as
`temp=# drop table ORDER;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ORDER"
LINE 1: drop table ORDER;`

What is the issue and what is other way to drop `ORDER` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER` is a reserved keyword as mentioned in:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

So it needs to be enclosed in double quotes when used as an object name. Besides, as it's in uppercase, even if it wasn't a keyword these double quotes would be needed anyway.

Just do:

```
drop table "ORDER";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `ORDER` is also a SQL "reserved word", you have to put the table name in double quotes.  (Which you have to do anyway because it is capitalized)